# Behavior of union with different data types

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I have two unions declared

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned short n1 : 4;
        unsigned int n2 : 4;
    } s;
    unsigned int val;

} unionA;


typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int n1 : 4;
        unsigned int n2 : 4;
    } s;
    unsigned int val;

} unionB;
```

I assign the same values to `val` as

```
    unionA uA;
    unionB uB;
    uA.val = 0xba;
    uB.val = 0xba;
```

I expected both the first nibble (represented by n1) to be `0xa` and the second nibble (represented by n2) to be `0xb` in both cases. However, it is `0xb` only in `unionB` . It is `0xc` in `unionA`.

[image]

I am running Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 11.

My understanding was the behavior had to be the same regardless of the datatype of the bitfields. What causes this difference?

Comment: The compiler (or should I say the C++ standard) does not give you any guarantee about actual byte representation. It only says the union should be able to store the largest member.

Comment: Also, type punning through unions is undefined behavior in C++. (But in C, it's allowed though.)

Comment: Thanks , this makes sense. The code I found this was in C.

Comment: Also the layout of bit-fields is implementation defined. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field#Notes

Comment: So moral of the story, don't use C code in C++ ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unions in C++ are not the same as unions in C. In C++, there is only one member *active* at any time, and reading from a non active member is *undefined behavior*. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

> The union is at least as big as necessary to hold its largest data member, but is usually not larger. The other data members are intended to be allocated in the same bytes as part of that largest member. The details of that allocation are implementation-defined, but all non-static data members will have the same address (since C++14). It is undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written.

Since `std::variant` (c++17) was introduced, I am not aware of any use of unions in C++. The purpose of a union is to save memory, not to perform type punning.